# Could not load a local nuget package. Strong name signature could not be verified

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, msbuild, nuget

I have ASP.Net project.

I built a new version for one of nuget package localy.

I included it to my project and VS is ok. I can see all updated entities end project has been built successful.

But when I try to open my site (localhost) I get the error:

**"Could not load file or assembly 'My local package' or one of its dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified.  The assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but not fully signed with the correct private key. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131045)"**

Wgen I did rollback to version from nuget everything is OK.

How can I fix signature for my local package?

Comment: Is this completely your own package or does it build on top of open source packages?

Comment: My package extends another remote package.